# jQuery set value of td cell depending on values of other cells using Array and if/else if

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I've Run into another problem trying to show different SLA statuses in the `slaClass` `td`.

I was previously using `console.log("red")` etc to show the statuses for testing. This worked perfectly, however when then trying to set the text for the `slaClass` field it just shows `Warning` and not the correct values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var daysLeft = $('.DaysLeft');
  var sla = $('.slaClass');
  $(daysLeft).each(function() {
    var daysLeft = $(this).text(); // assign a current value to increase its performance.

    if (daysLeft != "" && daysLeft != undefined) {
      if (parseInt(daysLeft) <= 30) {
        console.log('Red');
        $(sla).text('Red');
      } else if (parseInt(daysLeft) > 30 && parseInt(daysLeft) < 90) {
        console.log('Warning');
        $(sla).text('Warning');
      } else if (parseInt(daysLeft) >= 90) {
        console.log('Green');
        $(sla).text('Green');
      }
    } else(alert("Error"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Applicants</th>
      <th>Interviews</th>
      <th>Offers</th>
      <th>Days Left to Fill </th>
      <th>SLA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>530</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">125</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">25</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>82</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">62</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo code - http://jsfiddle.net/ZmesE/294/

Comment: Does your demo code not work in a StackOverflow snippet?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not grabbing the sibling ".slaClass" element from your current ".daysLeft" element.

Try this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
               var daysLeft = $('.DaysLeft');

                $(daysLeft).each(function() {
                    var daysLeft=$(this).text(); // assign a current value to increase its performance.
        var sla = $(this).siblings('.slaClass');
                    if(daysLeft !="" && daysLeft!=undefined)
                    {
                       if (parseInt(daysLeft) <= 30) {
                           console.log('Red');
                           $(sla).text('Red');
                        }else if (parseInt(daysLeft) > 30 && parseInt(daysLeft) < 90) {
                           console.log('Warning');
                           $(sla).text('Warning');
                        }else if (parseInt(daysLeft) >= 90) {
                           console.log('Green');
                           $(sla).text('Green');
                        }
                   }
                   else(alert("Error"));
                })
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're updating *all* the `.slaClass` elements instead of the one related to the current `.DaysLeft` element in the `each` iteration. To fix this, use `closest()` to get the parent `tr` of the current element. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.DaysLeft').each(function() {
    var $sla = $(this).closest('tr').find('.slaClass');
    var daysLeft = $(this).text();

    if (daysLeft != "" && daysLeft != undefined) {
      if (parseInt(daysLeft) <= 30) {
        console.log('Red');
        $sla.text('Red');
      } else if (parseInt(daysLeft) > 30 && parseInt(daysLeft) < 90) {
        console.log('Warning');
        $sla.text('Warning');
      } else if (parseInt(daysLeft) >= 90) {
        console.log('Green');
        $sla.text('Green');
      }
    } else(alert("Error"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Applicants</th>
      <th>Interviews</th>
      <th>Offers</th>
      <th>Days Left to Fill </th>
      <th>SLA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>530</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">125</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">25</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>82</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="DaysLeft">62</td>
      <td class="slaClass"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that in your original logic `DaysLeft` and `slaClass` are already jQuery objects, so you don't need to put them in jQuery objects again.

It's also not a good idea to re-use the same variable name, even if it is in a different scope. That could very easily lead to some unnecessary confusion.

Comment: May I be allowed to add my opinion to your answer? I suggest to use `.next()`

Comment: @TânNguyễn that's an alternative, but I prefer the use of `closest()` and `find()` as it's more robust. If a designer/HTML editor changes the order of the fields, or adds a new one in between, this logic will still work. Using `next()` would break. Perhaps not important when working alone or in a small team, but in enterprise level apps with a large distributed team, it can be a big problem.